# How to prove that the improper integral $\int^{\infty}_{1}\frac{\ln{x}}{1+x^2}dx$ is convergent?

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, convergence-divergence

How to prove that the improper integral $\int^{\infty}_{1}\frac{\ln{x}}{1+x^2}dx$ is convergent?

I tried both basic and limit comparison but I couldn't find a proper measure. i.e. $\frac{\ln{x}}{1+x^2}\le \frac{x}{1+x^2}$, but $\frac{x}{1+x^2}$ diverge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\ln x < 2\sqrt x$ for *all* $x>0$, hence

$$0\le \int_1^\infty\frac{\ln x}{1+x^2}\,\mathrm d\mkern1mu x\le\int_1^\infty\frac{\sqrt x}{1+x^2}\,\mathrm d\mkern1mu x\le\int_1^\infty\frac{\sqrt x}{x^2}\,\mathrm d\mkern1mu x=\int_1^\infty\frac1{x^{3/2}}\,\mathrm d\mkern1mu x,$$
which converges.

Answer (score 2):

**hint**: $\ln x < \sqrt{x}$  for large enough $x$.

Comment: Does that mean basic comparison? But I can't find a way to compute $\int^{\infty}_{1}\frac{\sqrt{x}}{1+x^2}dx$

Answer (score 2):

One may write
$$
0<\int^{\infty}_{1}\frac{\ln{x}}{1+x^2}dx<\int^{\infty}_{1}\frac{\ln{x}}{x^2}dx=\left[-\frac{1}{x}-\frac{\ln x}{x}\right]^{\infty}_{1}=1
$$ giving the convergence of the initial integral.

Comment: How did you do the integration to $-\frac{1}{x}-\frac{\ln{x}}{x}$?

Comment: A direct integration by parts $$\int^{\infty}_{1}\frac{\ln{x}}{x^2}dx=\left[-\frac{\ln x}{x}\right]^{\infty}_{1}+\int^{\infty}_{1}\frac1{x^2}dx=1$$